# Lubuntu 12.10 : won't boot, won't let to boot from LiveCD/USB either

Tags: lubuntu, boot-failure, live-usb, live-cd

After a force reboot Lubuntu "boots" into a black screen with a blinking cursor. When trying to boot from LiveCD/USB I get the same result, so I can't access the system at all. BIOS update didn't help. Can you help me?

EDIT: I had successful boots prior to that one and I used the exact same liveusb, so I doubt there were installation/liveusb problems. How do I access the terminal when in "blinking cursor mode" ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reinstall Lubuntu? Because maybe during the instalation process occurred problems that affected the system initialization.

Other explanation for this is that the Lubuntu image in your Live CD/USB can be corrupted, you can try downloading Lubuntu again to use as Live CD/USB.

A third explanation, that occurred with me already, is that the Startup Disk Creator you are using to create the Live CD/USB can be broken, then you can reinstall it's package with the command:

```
 sudo apt-get --reinstall install usb-creator-gtk
```

And now you should have your Disk Creator fixed.